# regex test for string or another

Tags: javascript, regex

This javascript regex tries to test for the presence of "him or her" and the number 1.5 in a given string but I am not able to get it to work. How can it be done? Thanks

```
if(/^(him)|(her).+?1\.5$/.test('working with him or her more than 1.5'))
```

Comment: Your first ^ means that the string should begin with him or her. You could remove "working with"  in the string or remove "^"  in the regexp

Comment: How *should* it work? Please specify your requirements. Should the result for the above be *true* or *false*? If you mean a string should have `him`, `her`, and `1.5`, you do not need a regex at all, use `indexOf`

Comment: Are you looking for the literal text `him or her` or is one of the terms `him` or `her` sufficient for a match? Should `there` also match (it contains `her`)? Should `11.55` match? Should `1.50` match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.*?` to test the presence of both strings

```
 /(him or her).*?(1\.5)/.test('working with him or her more than 1.5')
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will help you to test for presence of 'him or her' and 1.5 through out your text.

> var reg = new RegExp("him or her.*1.5|1.5.*him or her/g");

Check out this working sample 
[Here](https://regex101.com/r/bT9oW6/1)

Answer (score 0):

Just `/(him or her)(.*)(1\.5)/g` should be enough to recognize all instances of strings `him or her` or `1.5` in the complete text. Note the `g` flag is for global search.

I have added the sample here: https://regex101.com/r/oN4aY3/3

Comment: He's looking for (`him` or `her`) *and* `1.5`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker He never mentioned that. I gave a simpler solution from what he had asked.

Comment: '...test for the presence of "him or her" and the number 1.5...' (not necessarily on the same line, correct. I removed that part from my comment).

Comment: @TimPietzcker I've updated the regex. You can remove your downvote.

Comment: "and". Not "or". I do agree that the question is still ambiguously worded, therefore my comment on the question itself. But the "and` part is clear.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Well it looks like the question was edited after I added my answer. I've updated for the and part though.